# use env variable as key in application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot

my application.yml look like as below:-

```
mydata:
  ${test_key}: 
    value1: test_value1
    value2: test_value2
```

**${test_key}** is set through env variable, but it seems this is not working, yml file is not picking up the value for ${test_key} from env variable and parse it.

**${test_key}** will change env to env so we want to pick this value from env variable

Could you please let me know how to achieve this ?

Comment: Why though? What's your use-case?

Comment: @knittl  this is a simple representation of the actual problem, ${test_key} will change environment to environment, so we want to set it using env variable for that environment rather than hard-coding the key

Comment: Can you use multiple application files and pick the right one on profile? You would have one profile per environment, e.g. `application-prod.yml`, `application-staging.yml`, `application-dev.yml` or maybe more explicit `application-env-prod.yml`

Comment: right now as the application using single application.yml and we cannot change this structure, so we are seeing the work around to make it work using env variable

Comment: But spring already supports multiple application files out of the box, you only need to put them in the directory to be picked up.

Comment: yeah I know, but our application is strictly following to maintain a single yml file though this is not good design, but we have no choice except follow the same, so could you please let me if we can do it this way ? is there any support in spring for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot can handle different application configuration files and loads them depending on profile. With YAML configuration, a single `application.yml` file can contain multiple documents and each document can be enabled for a certain profile.

How properties and profiles are loaded has changed with Spring Boot 2.4 and you can read the details in the Spring blog: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4.

So it is not possible to expand variables in keys, but you can define multiple profiles in a single file:

**`application.yml`**:

```
spring.profiles: env-prod
mydata:
  prod: 
    value1: test_value1
    value2: test_value2
---
spring.profiles: env-staging
mydata:
  staging:
    value1: test_value1
    value2: test_value2
```

Then you can start your application with `--spring-profiles-active=env-staging` or `--spring-profiles-active=env-prod`.

But now, whenever you read the config, you also need to use the correct key. So I would suggest not changing the key depending on environment, but instead use the same key and load different configuration on environment/profile. I'm pretty sure that changing the key makes the overall design of your application more complicated.